# How to return a count of the number of numbers read or N, whichever is smaller in an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm confused about how the function below can be worked so that it can read the numbers from a data file, place the numbers in the array A and return a count of the number of numbers read or N, whichever is smaller.

```
#include <stdio.h>
{
    int readNumbers(FILE* input,int A[],int N)
    int n;
    n = 0;
    while(n < N&&!feof(input))
    {
        fscanf_s(input,"%f",&A[n]));
        n++;
    }
}
```

The above program should read a file of numbers and place them into an array. I'm just stuck on how I would program in a count of the number of numbers read or N.

Comment: add `return n;` before the final `}`

Comment: You may want to delete the question now that the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

1 Wrong scanf() usage

```
int readNumbers(FILE* input,int A[],int N)
...
// fscanf_s(input,"%f",&A[n]));
fscanf_s(input, "%d", &A[n]));
```

2 Rather than using `feof()` incorrectly - it should be used *after* `fscanf_s()` return EOF to distinguish a `feof()` from `ferror()`.

```
while(n < N && fscanf_s(input,"%d", &A[n]) != EOF) {
  ...
}
```

3 As @Hogan says, add return n;

4 Syntax error: change

```
{
int readNumbers(FILE* input,int A[],int N)
// to
int readNumbers(FILE* input,int A[],int N) {
```